# how to compare date and display upcoming weeks data?

Tags: angular, ionic2

**Requirement--** I want to display data of upcoming week.
**Current position--** Below is my html code, i used *ngIf to compare deadline_date(list.deadline_dt) with today's date(this.datt1).I used date format (dd-MM-yy) but it does not compare two dates. so, i use 'timeAgo'.but still its not working.

```
<ion-card>
<ion-card-header>
  Upcoming Week Tasks to do
</ion-card-header>
<ion-card-content>
  <!-- Add card content here! -->

  <ion-list *ngFor="let list of dataa" >

    <ion-item class="desc" *ngIf="(list.DEADLINE_DT | timeAgo) >= (this.datt1 | timeAgo)">
      <p style="color:#9ea5a9; margin-top:10px" item-start>{{list.TASKDESC}}</p>
      <p style="color:green"> {{list.DEADLINE_DT}} </p>
      <p style="color:#9ea5a9; margin-top:10px" item-end>{{list.ENTUSR }}</p>
      <hr/>

    </ion-item>

  </ion-list>

</ion-card-content>
```

**.ts**

```
public datt=new Date();
 this.datt1=this.datepipe.transform(this.datt,'dd-MMM-yy');
console.log(this.datt1,"sysdat");
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBwGI.png)

Comment: where does the timeAgo pipe come from?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the timeAgo pipe tells you how far in the past a time is? I don't think we need that. You want to display the upcoming week which is not in the past. Also, you shouldn't need to pipe a Date object through anything in order to compare two dates. You can just compare them directly.

I'm guessing a problem is that you're comparing it to `this.datt1`. Is that a property of the component/page class? If so, you shouldn't put `this`, you just reference it with `datt1`.

Comment: Yes, in the template you don't reference properties with `this`, you just use the name of the property.

Comment: Do you have any questions about my answer?